# Ajax - reload previus data in div after search field is emptied

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a small `ajax` script with which i'm searching and loading results without reloading or redirecting the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#db-search').keyup(function(){

    var txt = $(this).val();

    if(txt != ''){
        $('#db-search-results').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search.php',
            method: 'post',
            data:{search:txt},
            dataType: 'text',
            success:function(data){
                $('#db-search-results').html(data);
            }
        });
    } else{
        //reload previus data
    }

});

});
```

It works but there is a problem. Before entering anything in `#db-search` field I'm already displaying all the results from the database inside `#db-search-results`. Now when I'm searching for something all that previous data is replaced with those new results but if I clear the search field my results are gone(which is ok) but my previous data isn't coming back.

Is there a way to keep previous data after clearing that search field?

P.S: currently i'm just performing a `SELECT *` query and then i'm loading it using `$('#db-search-results').html('search.php');` but that's an extra query and I would rather search for another way of doing this :D

Comment: you need store it in some variable outside this function and get it in else part.

Comment: @user6761351, hey can you please tell me how can i do that?

Comment: Instead of querying your server for data on every keypress, you should filter the data you already have. Use JS to "hide" the data that doesn't match the keyword(s).

Comment: how you are getting the previous data ?
i will think about a hack otherwise.

Comment: So, filtering works reasonably easy. Basicly you use JS to loop through the result (DOM). Like for example your result is: `<div>Data row 1</div><div>Data row 2</div>` etc. The text between those rows can be selected with `element.innerText`. Then you just check if the search word(s) is found inside it. If not, you use JS to change the elements CSS to `display: none;`. That way the element disappears. If it does match, change to `display: block;` so it appears again. Do this loop on each keypress and you're done. No need to query your server every single time.

Comment: @icecub, i'm officially lost X_X

Comment: Ye I was afraid of that. It's not something I can teach you so easily through Stack Overflow. Give me some time. I'll create a JSFiddle with some example code so you can see how it works. That'll probably help a lot :)

Comment: @icecub thank youuuuuuuuuuuu! <3 :D i am waiting, let me know if i can...stay in your way with something :D

Comment: Alright, here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/k5tujqgo/23/

Comment: @icecub, this is sooo much fun :D i have only one question: can it be made to work in a case insensitive mode? X_X

Comment: Sure! Just change this: `if($(this).text().indexOf($("#search_input").val()) >= 0){` to `if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($("#search_input").val()) >= 0){`

Comment: Wait no, that won't work. Lemme check

Comment: @emma  client side filtering sucks if there is a lot of data. So doing api call is a better approach when there is a large data set.

Comment: Here I've updated it. This is case insensitive: http://jsfiddle.net/k5tujqgo/26/

Comment: @user6761351, oky, thank you! I don't have such a larg data set, most of the items that i want to allow my users to be able to search for are only 1 or 2 words long but all of them are case insensitive X_X

Comment: @icecub, o my gooood this is sooo genius !! <3 I can't thank you enough :D i'm actually smiling-in-awe :O:D. O god, thank you Ice :D!!! Can i bother you with some other questions later? X_X

Comment: Sure, just lemme know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store it in a variable once the page is loaded and display it when you need like :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var default_data = $('#db-search-results').html();

    $('#db-search').keyup(function(){
        var txt = $(this).val();

        if(txt != ''){
            $('#db-search-results').html('');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'search.php',
                method: 'post',
                data:{search:txt},
                dataType: 'text',
                success:function(data){
                    $('#db-search-results').html(data);
                }
            });
        } else{
            $('#db-search-results').html(default_data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thank youuuu! it worked :D thank you thank you thank youuu <3

Comment: sister but thank youu, it took me 2h and i still couldn't understand it :D<3

Comment: Ohh really sorry @emma I didn't see the name, Glad I could help again (y)

Comment: I still believe filtering the data would be a far better solution. She already queries all the data so it's there. That server is gonna hang very fast if too many visitors are searching at the same time cuz of all the `SELECT` queries.

Comment: @icecub, can you please explain it a little bit more...detailed? :D

Comment: @emma Will do in some mins. Got a phonecall

Comment: @icecub, oky, i'm waiting :D

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var previousData=''; 

$('#db-search').keyup(function(){

    var txt = $(this).val();

    if(txt != ''){
        $('#db-search-results').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'search.php',
            method: 'post',
            data:{search:txt},
            dataType: 'text',
            success:function(data){
                previousData=data;
                $('#db-search-results').html(data);

            }
        });
    } else{
        //reload previus data
         $('#db-search-results').html(previousData);
    }

});

});
```

Comment: previousData means the data which was there before user searched anything.

Comment: I suppose previousData means the previous search results till the results are replaced by new search results.

Comment: hey @VenkatD, thank you for taking time to answer to my question!